# PHP5-IMAP 'I aint got no body!'

Tags: php, imap

Here is a strange one for you.

I am using the `Ipipi SMS` to email service to send control commands to a `PHP` script.

I can send email messages to my mailbox, then read and display them using `PHP-IMAP` commands as in this code segment:

`$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
    echo $message;`

If I send a sms message to the `mailbox imap_fetchbody`, it returns empty.

However, if I then read the mailbox with a email client the message is there. I do not think it is an `Ipipi` issue.

If I do a `var_dump($message)` I get `string(0) ""`.

Comment: Have you looked to see if the wireless carrier is forming the email headers correctly?

Comment: I have, perhaps naively, assumed that if Thunderbird can read the message, then the headers must be OK.

Comment: It'd help to have a sample message.

Comment: **Why do you use email?** It is *slow*. *Very* slow. Why don't you open up a port in your PHP script? I don't know if this is possible, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you issue

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
```

you're asking for the content of part 2 of the message.  (That's what the [third argument to `imap_fetchbody`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php) means.)

```
string imap_fetchbody ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number ,
                        string $section [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

It's hard to know without being able to see a sample message from the SMS gateway, but I'd guess that your message isn't a multipart and thus it doesn't have a part 2.  What happens if you substitute a `1` for the `2` when fetching this particular message?

(In general, you'll want to look at the message structure before deciding which body part to fetch.  You can use [`imap_fetchstructure`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) for this.)

Comment: dkarp : You are the main man!

Replacing the '2' with a '1' gets it working. Also a standard email still works.

My problem is that I picked the code up off the web. Having tested that it worked with a standard email I was stumped when it did not work with the sms email.

I had assumed, wrongly, that '2' was the standard body part to request. Silly me.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @BillP: If this answered your question, please [click on the checkmark outline](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to the left of the answer. It makes the solution clear to the next person with the same issue...