# How to use IMAP in PHP to fetch mail body content?

Tags: php, imap

I can't fetch email body content.

This is my code

```
<?php
/* connect to server */
$hostname = '{myserver/pop3/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Tiriyo: ' . imap_last_error());
//echo $inbox;
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');


/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

  /* begin output var */
  $output = '';

  /* put the newest emails on top */
  rsort($emails);

  /* for every email... */
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
    //$email_number=$emails[0];
//print_r($emails);
    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

    /* output the email header information */
    $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
    $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
    $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
    $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
    $output.= '</div>';

    /* output the email body */
    $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
  }

  echo $output;
}

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```

When I use to fetch email from Gmail, the email body content is displayed, but once I use my mail server, I can't fetch the body content of email.

Can you help me fix this problem?

Comment: What mail server are you using?

Comment: Tested it; your script is working fine with Gmail as you said.  The errors are probably coming from your mail server.  Are there any other details you can provide?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170489/php5-imap-i-aint-got-no-body

Comment: Try https://github.com/MonstaApps/PHP-IMAP-Fetcher. Pipe or fetch emails, log to MySQL, and save attachments.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I had found solution,
Error is with this line

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
```

Now, I am using

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1.2);
```

To receive body content in text/html format

Below i had given datails of available options. This might some one

```
()Root Message Part (multipart/related)
(1) The text parts of the message (multipart/alternative)
(1.1) Plain text version (text/plain)
(1.2) HTML version (text/html)
(2) The background stationary (image/gif)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching the exact same thing... That's why is also good to check the docs jaja... I just copy/paste an example from Internet and expected to work...

Comment: look up fetch_structure, u need to decode the message if it is encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The Zeta Mail component allows much more [convenient fetching of mails from IMAP](http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html#retrieving-mail-using-imap) and [POP](http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html#retrieving-mail-using-pop3) and can parses the incoming emails into a nice and clean object structure so you can handle it easily.

Comment: He's using POP, not IMAP.  Check the first parameter to the `imap_open` call.

Comment: Sorry, got that wrong. However, works with POP too: http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/documentation/trunk/Mail/tutorial.html#retrieving-mail-using-pop3

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that IMAP and POP is both possible.