# php imap reading body message

Tags: php, email

I am writing a simple php script for reading emails.

When I extract mail body with:

```
imap_body($mbox, $i);
```

I have returned something like this:

```
--0016e6db2b334d4d7904a883f4ec 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 

<The message arrived> 

--0016e6db2b334d4d7904a883f4ec 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 

<The message arrived> 

--0016e6db2b334d4d7904a883f4ec--
```

How can I extract only: ?
I am using php_imap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using IMAP, you can use the imap_body() function to read the body.
PHP has ton of functions that will help you with parsing an email.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php

Check out the fetch_body() function too.  It will allow you to get just part of the body.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php

For example:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1.2);
```

Comment: the problem is that the entire string is printed by imap_body($mbox, $i);

Comment: Have you tried fetch_body()?

`imap_fetchbody ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number , string $section [, int $options = 0 ] )`

The section is the argument that you can send to get the main body.

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177772/how-to-use-imap-in-php-to-fetch-mail-body-content

Comment: I've edited my original answer with an example of how to the the html text from an email using fetch_body()

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in future asking same question, this code worked for me:

```php
imap_fetchbody($this->connection, $sequence, 1);
```