# php extracting text/plain from mail body

Tags: php, email, imap

this is the content of one mail read by imap_php library.
I would extract the content-type text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 text:

```
{"data":"10/10/2011","regione":"pt","provincia":"pistoia","nome":"nome","tel":"12345","email":"mymailaddress","richiesta":"qualcosa"}
```

If I use imap_body($mbox, $result[0])  i have returned all the text in the box.
If I use imap_fetchbody($mbox,$email_number,2);  I have returned the text/html body message that i don't want.

> --20cf301e2f27a218c204a88578aa Content-Type: text/plain;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1 
>   {"data":"10/10/2011","regione":"pt","provincia":"pistoia","nome":"nome","tel":"12345","email":"mymailaddress","richiesta":"qualcosa"}
>
> --20cf301e2f27a218c204a88578aa Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding:  quoted-printable 
>   {"data&= quot;:"10/10/2011","regione":"pt","provi=
>   ncia":"pistoia","nome":"nome","tel&=
>   quot;:"12345","email":"mymailaddress","r= ichiesta":"qualcosa"}
>   --20cf301e2f27a218c204a88578aa--

So what I have to use if I want the text/plain body? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a look at the [imap_fetchbody](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php) docs, you'll find [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php#89002) that will probably be of use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use 1.1 as the section argument to fetch_body()
For example:

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1.1);
```

[How to use IMAP in PHP to fetch mail body content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177772/how-to-use-imap-in-php-to-fetch-mail-body-content)

Answer (score 5):

You Can also try these

```
content-type:text/html

$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 2);

content-type:plaintext/text

$message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 1);
```

More explanation about [imap_fetchbody](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php)

Comment: I am falling-back to this if the 1.1 and 1.2 does not yield content.